# Accessing final static class with package-private constructor from outside the package

Tags: java, mocking

I have a class that I can't modify that looks as follows:

```
public class ValueSupplier {

public static final class Value {
    private final Long id;

    private final String value1;
    private final String value2;

    Value(Long id, String value1, String value2) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    // getters omitted
}
```

Is there anyway I could use that static **Value** class outside of the package that class resides without using reflection? I guess not but worth asking. List is returned from some method in ValueSupplier and wanted to mock that method but can't return List because I don't have access to that package.

If using reflection - what is the simplest and most clear solution?

Edit:
I meant creating an instance of it via constructor - that's my problem.

Comment: The class is public, so you should be able to access it. Whether you can use its members is a different story. And also, as the class is final, you'll have challenges mocking it anyway. Is it something you can't change? Maybe reflection is your only option.

Comment: I can't change it. And you are right - I meant creating an instance of it using constructor.

Comment: @doublemc, add a `public static` factory method to bypass a constructor call

Comment: Have you tried using reflection yet? Are you having any difficulty?

Comment: @Andrew I can't modify this class

Comment: @cricket_007 I haven't but I am going to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the nested class can't be modified, Reflection API is the only option.

The primary idea is to obtain a constructor (1), make it accessible (2) via [`AccessibleObject#setAccessible`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(boolean)) and invoke it (3).

```
import <package>.ValueSupplier;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class ClassFromAnotherPackage {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void methodFromAnotherPackage()
            throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {

        final Constructor<?>[] constructors = ValueSupplier.Value.class.getDeclaredConstructors();

        if (constructors.length > 0) {
            final Constructor<ValueSupplier.Value> constructor = (Constructor<ValueSupplier.Value>) constructors[0]; // 1
            constructor.setAccessible(true); // 2
            final ValueSupplier.Value value = constructor.newInstance(1L, "str1", "str2"); // 3
        }

    }

}
```